# Will Ethereum 2.0 support light-clients?

Tags: light-clients, eth-2.0

I am new to Ethereum, and I am trying to understand how different eth2 will be from eth1 in terms of connecting to the network and performing tasks. For example, in eth1 we don't need to be miners to connect to the network and submit transactions. We can simply use Geth's ethclient to connect to the Infura gateway. By contrast, I haven't been able to find any information about this kind of light-clients designed for eth2. Will eth2 demand each client to participate as a full beacon node/validator? Or will it be possible to connect to the shard chains directly using ethclient in some future release?

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed https://notes.ethereum.org/@vbuterin/HF1_proposal , so it looks like the current Eth2 beacon chain doesn't support light nodes.

The proposal is aiming to introduce the possibility for light nodes, although there are very few details. If this proposal is implemented as-is, it looks to me like there is still a lot of work to do before a real light client can be implemented. For example where is the state root "snapshot" data stored and retrieved from.